# floating elements next to each other

Tags: html, css, floating-accuracy

I am making a website and i want somthing like so:

img text img

img text img

img text img

the images will be on the left and right side of the screen, but when i float an image to the right it is under the images on the left. Here is an example:[image] So how would i have the images on the same level with a p or div tag in-between them. Any help is appreciated

Edit: if i float my images and p tag to the left this is what i get:[image]

how would i have the image on the right hand side to be on the end of the screen?

Comment: Why don't you use display:inline-block; add this to both images and delete the float.

Comment: can you explain in jsfiddle what are you expecting .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating can be a bit difficult for beginners. First read up on it on sites like [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) When placing images next to each other in your example, both images should float in one direction.

```
img{
 float:left;
}
```

Also, floats should be cleared when putting content beneath it. Read more on clearing on the same site as above.

Comment: No, don't read up on it on w3schools. Read up on it on reliable sources.

Comment: W3school is good, do you have a prob with that?